# c# how to call class from class file

Tags: c#, cmd

I have this class but I don't know how to call it. Sorry but I am new and I still learn. With this class i try to open MS SQL Ports. May be have different way but like I said i still learn.

```
public class ProcessStart
    {
        public string input;
        public static void startProcess(string input)
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            input = @"
@echo Enabling SQLServer default instance port 1433
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name =""SQLServer"" dir =in action = allow protocol = TCP localport = 1433
@echo Enabling Dedicated Admin Connection port 1434
@echo Enabling HTTP port 80
@netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=""SqlServer1"" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80
@echo Enabling Dedicated Admin Connection port 80
";
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.Start();
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(input);
            process.StandardInput.Flush();
            process.StandardInput.Close();
            process.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            //Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
```

Comment: `ProcessStart.startProcess("your input value");`

Comment: i try the same but without "".... Thank you bro!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `startProcess` is *public* you can call it from outside the class. Because it’s *static* you can call it without creating an instance. So:

```cs
ProcessStart.startProcess(input);
```

Furthermore, you’ll need a static `Main` method somewhere, for example:

```
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        …
    }
}
```

It doesn’t matter what class the `Main()` method is defined in. You could add it to `ProcessStart`.

**Edit:** there is something strange about your class: you declare an unused *non-static* `input` member on your class, as well as an `input` argument that you then ignore because you overwrite it on the second line. You can remove the member variable and choose to either use the passed-in argument value, or remove the argument and declare it in the method body:

```
class ProcessStart {
    public static void startProcess(string input) {
        Process process = new Process();
        // Don’t assign input here! Use the argument.
        process.StartInfo. …
        …
    }
}
```

or

```
class ProcessStart {
    public static void startProcess() { // No argument
        Process process = new Process();
        string input = @"…";
        process.StartInfo. …
        …
    }
}
```